# Assert a property's type on existence of another property on union type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

Is it possible to assert a property's type, on an existence of another property?

For example:

```js
interface Base {
    field1: number;
}

interface Sub1 extends Base {
    field3: string;
    field2?: never;
}

interface Sub2 extends Base {
    field3: number;
    field2: string;
}

type Unionized = Sub1 | Sub2

function MyFunc(union: Unionized) {
    if (union.field2) {
        // expect union.field3 to be a number
        // But instead it is a union of string | number
        console.log(union.field3)
    }
}
```

I expect from the above code, when `union.field2` exists, `union.field3` should be of type `number` from the `Sub2` interface, but it is inferred as `string | number`.

Is this possible?

**Edit 1**: added screenshot

[image: union]

Comment: The main approach is to declare common field as literal in each separate type and use it for such purpose.

Comment: Yes, discriminated unions. I was wondering if a similar thing can be done on checking existence of another property.

Comment: your code seems to behave like you expect it to in codesandbox

Comment: Which TS Version are you using? For me it works as you want it in TS 4.0, check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnIzAQA2AJgIwBcyIArgLYBG0A3LgL666iSyIoAynSYVkEAB6QQZDGkw58hYuQDMNDGCigA5uwJFSZAEwB+GiAgA3Np269o8JMmFNj4qRBlz0WZHgMVMnVaRhYofWUjYw0tXXYuXDAATwAHFABVEGAAe2yALwgyZABeFxExAB9yt24YOhAEMFyQZABZZIAxBoQACgaWmiyW4EKyAEp-JWAYZH7svIA6Q3JjSYCCZAB6LY90puQBpZXg5DAc5BZkOFDmaCUCHbQ6MGRQTQg4YuBX4Dkbo6tHKzTTaEA6ZDVeh3KAPZAIPIYHIkCCLEg5HTzFrLIKqcZKLgcIA) link

Comment: In your case declared ```field2``` in ```Sub1``` considered as existing regardless of its type, even when it typed as ```never```. I think to hint TS about non-existing property it should be deleted.

Comment: @Zer0 that's weird. I'm also using TS 4.0.2. Edited my question to add screenshot.

Comment: is it also 4.0.2 in your package.json or whatever config you use? @WildanMaulanaSyahidillah

Comment: I tried it on an empty project, it is still the same.